# Does Ubuntu Server work on HP MicroServer G7 N54L?

Tags: hardware, hp

I want to purchase a HP MicroServer G7 N54L , but I want to be sure that Ubuntu Server will work fine on it !
I want to use the `systemen` as MySQL database server.

Comment: What server version of Ubuntu u use to install on the HP MicroServer G7 N54L

Answer (score 0):

One Word: **Yes!!!** it will work.

Comment: What server version of Ubuntu u use to install on the HP MicroServer G7 N54L

Comment: You can use the Long Term Support version i.e. Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.